# rake aborted! uninitialized constant Mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
Goksel-Eryigits-Mac-mini:blog geryit$ rake db:migrate --trace
(in /Users/geryit/Sites/blog)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
/Users/geryit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/mysql.rb:453:in `read'
/Users/geryit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/mysql.rb:130:in `real_connect'
/Users/geryit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:600:in `connect'
/Users/geryit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:164:in `initialize
.
.
.
```

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They work together now without any problems. The problem was Mysql version and mysql gem flags. I removed MYSQL 5.5 and installed Mysql 5.1 back. Everything is fixed. Thanks.

I wrote a blog post about installing, it can be helpful : https://geryit.com/blog/installing-mysql-with-rails-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/

Comment: that's a rubbish sultion! I can't see myself avoiding the best version of mysql (5.5) because a gem file.

Answer (score 11):

Have you defined

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

in Gemfile? For Rails 3 and Bundler, it's not enough to install the gem, but to include it in Gemfile.

Comment: I fixed the problem. The problem was my Mysql Version. I uninstalled Mysql 5.5 and installed 5.1 . Everything works fine now. Thanks.
I already write a blog post about this issue : http://geryit.com/blog/2011/01/installing-mysql-with-rails-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling the `mysql` gem. It might be conflicting with the `mysql2` gem you're using in your `database.yml`.

Comment: They work together now without any problems. The problem was Mysql version and mysql gem flags. Now everything is fixed. Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I've had problems when using both at the same time in the past. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting 'uninitialized constant Mysql' on Snow Leopard and Rails 3. Adding 'mysql' gem to Gemfile fixed it for me.