# rake db:create not working with mysql database (OS X)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I just did a fresh install of RVM, JRuby, Rails, and MySQL, but I am having some trouble creating my databases. When I run `rake db:create --trace` I get the following output:

```
rake db:create --trace
JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Mysql::Error
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:64:in `create_database'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:33:in `(root)'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/max/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `(root)'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.4/bin/rake:19:in `(root)'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

I have no idea what could be wrong. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the mysql gem in the Gemfile and did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: http://infinite-sushi.com/2010/07/uninitialized-constant-mysqlerror-with-rails-3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using Snow Leopard?

The problem might be in Mysql version and gem flags. Remove Mysql 5.5 if you have (Mysql 5.1 is a stable version)

have a look in here  [rake aborted! uninitialized constant Mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697881/rake-aborted-uninitialized-constant-mysql2)  and here http://geryit.com/blog/2011/01/installing-mysql-with-rails-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/

Comment: I use ubuntu and I'm not sure how things work on Macs but would have suggested that the mysql service isn't running. Even though I'm on linux I still have to restart my computer on occasion and I forget to restart mysql. It's bitten me in my posterior more than once.

Comment: On OS X you can install a preferences pane for MySQL. This gives you instant visual confirmation that MySQL is running. I also installed a startup item for the MySQL server, so MySQL is always running unless I explicitly tell it to stop or it crashes.