# precompiling assets failing on remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Everything is working fine locally, but when I do: bundle exec rake assets:precompile on the server, here's what I get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
/mnt/home/bigdata/config/initializers/special_mysql_types.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/mnt/home/bigdata/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ru...]
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Following is the output of the gem list command:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
capistrano (2.15.4)
capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
commonjs (0.2.6)
daemon_controller (1.1.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
formtastic (2.2.1)
formtastic-bootstrap (2.1.1)
highline (1.6.18)
hike (1.2.2)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1)
json (1.7.7)
less (2.3.2)
less-rails (2.3.3)
libv8 (3.11.8.17 x86_64-linux)
mail (2.5.3)
mime-types (1.23)
multi_json (1.7.3)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-scp (1.1.0)
net-sftp (2.1.1)
net-ssh (2.6.7)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
passenger (4.0.0.rc6)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4)
rdoc (3.12.2)
ref (1.0.4)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.7)
sass (3.2.8)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
therubyracer (0.11.4)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.4.1, 1.4.0)
treetop (1.4.12)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.6)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.0, 2.0.1)
```

Local environment is Mac Mountain Lion, server is generic AWS Linux. Any ideas?

Here's what's in config/initializers/special_mysql_types.rb (migration files are properly processed locally and the DB tables are created without a problem).

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:big_int_primary_auto_inc] = "BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment"
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:big_int_non_primary] = "BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL"
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:int_unsigned] = "INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL"
```

This is an example of how I would use it in a migration file:

```
class CreateTweets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tweets, id: false do |t|
      t.column :id, :big_int_primary_auto_inc
      t.column :tweet_id, :big_int_non_primary
      t.string :tweet_text, limit: 160
    end
  end
end
```

This is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: big_data_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: xxxxxxxx
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: big_data_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: xxxxxxxx #this is an AWS RDS instance
  database: bigdata
  username: bigdata
  password: xxxxxx
```

Comment: What is going on in `/mnt/home/bigdata/config/initializers/special_mysql_types.rb`?

Comment: Please see my edits to the question. I did this to force the id field to be unsigned bigint, and to create a bigint and int unsigned for some other fields. I deal with social media data, hence the need for these fields.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper take a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697881/rake-aborted-uninitialized-constant-mysql2 this may help

Comment: I already have mysql2 listed as a gem in my gemfile and the issue is on a linux server, not my local environment. Locally, on my MAC, I have no issues (as in my development environment). I also have no control over the server's MySQL server, which is running MySQL 5.2.27

Comment: how does your database.yml look like?

Comment: Added it database.yml to the question