# mysql2 gemerror with older ruby on rail versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I have this versions, and I cannot change the ruby and rail versions

- ruby version - 1.9.2-p290
- rail version  - 3.0.9
- mysql2 version - 0.2.9

when I try to run  `rails server command` on Ubuntu, I am getting this error

```
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'mysql2'.
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::SECURE_CONNECTION
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.9/lib/mysql2/client.rb:12:in `<class:Client>'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.9/lib/mysql2/client.rb:2:in `<module:Mysql2>'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.9/lib/mysql2/client.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.9/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
/home/xyz/Documents/trailtap-api/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/xyz/Documents/trailtap-api/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
/home/xyz/Documents/trailtap-api/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/Documents/trailtap-api/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I thought gem file needed to be update so I updated it but then mysql2 doesnot support rail version and doesnot ship active record adapter, even after installing adapter gem it fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try **bundle update**

Answer (score 0):

Check this article: [uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::SECURE_CONNECTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034324/uninitialized-constant-mysql2clientsecure-connection)

Solution was to upgrade mysql2. In your case, might be worth trying downgrading the that version and see if it fixes your issue.

Also, make sure that `libmysqlclient-dev` and `ruby-mysql` are installed and up-to-date

Comment: when I try to install libmysqlclient-dev, doensot find any repo for that. and I dont think upgrading mysql2 version will work , because it gives error as mention above. I am looking for solution which allows mysql2 version to work

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'mysql2', "0.2.24"
```